# list all token IDs by owner at ERC721

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js, ipfs

I have a simple ERC721 smart contract used for testing purposes, I was wondering if it is possible to query the token IDs a specific wallet owns in that smart contract.

eventually I would like to display the NFTs minted by the user in the website.

balanceOf in the contract returns the number of tokens owned by the user, but no further info.

my test smart contract:

https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/token/0x263d3b61ad4f4c44f694a4464a8f2a0b6514c064?a=0x330d7ac5f24dc3570c2afe3f3a57d9c66e0795e8#readContract

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like your contract inherits an extension of ERC721 called ERC721Enumerable.

This extension adds a function called `tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address owner, uint256 index)`, which can used to list all tokens owned by a user (`owner`). So you can call this function multiple times, looping `index` from `0` to `balanceOf(owner)` to get all tokens ids.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to get IDs from a `ERC721Enumerable` contract was to deploy a simple helper contract that arrogates the `tokenOfOwnerByIndex()` loop into 1 call.

Here's my contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Enumerable.sol';

contract getIDs {

    function getWalletIDFromContract (address _contract, address wallet, uint256 bal) external view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        uint256[] memory ids = new uint256[](bal);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < bal; i++) {
            ids[i] = IERC721Enumerable(_contract).tokenOfOwnerByIndex(wallet, i);
        }
        return ids;
    }
    
}
```